# Binding one combobox to another combobox in while loop in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, bind

*I wanted to bind platform_id drop combobox to teh combobox_b so taht if cpu is selected in platform_id_drop, then cpu frequencies must be listed otherwise gpu frequencies must be listed. I am using while loop to create a number of rows based on input we are giving and used dictionary to store respective columns. I am able to get only fo rone set of row i.e frequencies are display oly for one row but not for other rows. Having Problem with bind function. Please help me with this.

'''

```
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile
import collections

app=Tk()
app.title("trace")
app.geometry("1000x500")
global z
required=2
z=required

global global_id
global_id=0
global text_file_3
global text_file_4

a_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
a_dict['global_id']={}
a_dict['unique_dag_id']={}
a_dict['platform_id']={}
a_dict['deadline']={}
a_dict['wcet_cpu']={}
a_dict['wcet_gpu']={}
a_dict['input_arrival_time']={}
a_dict['hyper_period_entry']={}
a_dict['input_task_period']={}
a_dict['frequency']={}

unique_dag_id = StringVar()
wcet_cpu = StringVar()
wcet_gpu = StringVar()
deadline = StringVar()
input_arrival_time = StringVar()
hyper_period_entry = StringVar()
input_task_period=StringVar()
frequency=StringVar()
last_county=StringVar()
v=[]
dict1={'gpu':['177000000' ,'266000000' ,'350000000' ,'420000000' ,'480000000', '543000000' , '600000000'],'cpu':['200000000', '300000000', '400000000', '500000000', '600000000', '700000000', '800000000', '900000000', '1000000000' ,'1100000000', '1200000000', '1300000000', '1400000000', '1500000000' ,'1600000000', '1700000000', '1800000000', '1900000000', '2000000000']}


def save_trace1():
    global global_id
    global_id_info=global_id_entry

    if(platform_id_drop.get()=='cpu'):
        platform_id_info=0
    else:
        platform_id_info=1
    
    unique_dag_id_info=unique_dag_id_entry
    wcet_cpu_info=wcet_cpu_entry.get()
    wcet_gpu_info=wcet_gpu_entry.get()
    deadline_info=deadline_entry.get()
    input_arrival_time_info=input_arrival_time_entry.get()
    hyper_period_entry_info=hyper_period_entry_entry.get()
    input_task_period_info=input_task_period_entry.get()
    combobox_b_info=combobox_b.get()
    
    for i in range(required):
        print(a_dict['platform_id'][i].get())

global_id_label=Label(text="global_id ")
platform_id_label=Label(text='platform_id')
unique_dag_id_label=Label(text='unique_dag-id')
wcet_cpu_label=Label(text='wcet_cpu')
wcet_gpu_label=Label(text='wcet_gpu')
deadline_label=Label(text='deadline')
input_arrival_time_label=Label(text='input-arrival time')
hyper_period_entry_label=Label(text='hyper_period_entry')
input_task_period_label=Label(text='input_task_period')
freq_label=Label(text='Frequency')
platform_id_options=[
    'cpu','gpu',
]

global_id_label.place(x=50,y=50)
platform_id_label.place(x=150,y=50)
unique_dag_id_label.place(x=330,y=50)
wcet_cpu_label.place(x=450,y=50)
wcet_gpu_label.place(x=600,y=50)
deadline_label.place(x=750,y=50)
input_arrival_time_label.place(x=900,y=50)
hyper_period_entry_label.place(x=1050,y=50)
input_task_period_label.place(x=1200,y=50)
freq_label.place(x=1350,y=50)

trace_entries=[]
dag_entries=[]

while(z>0):
   
    #platform_id_drop.pack(pady=20)
    def selo(eventobj):
        v=[]
        if(platform_id_drop.get()=='cpu'):
            print("a")
            v=['200000000', '300000000', '400000000', '500000000', '600000000',
'700000000', '800000000', '900000000', '1000000000' ,'1100000000', '1200000000', '1300000000', '1400000000', '1500000000' ,'1600000000', '1700000000', '1800000000', '1900000000', '2000000000']
        elif(platform_id_drop.get()=='gpu'):
            print("m")
            v=['177000000' ,'266000000' ,'350000000' ,'420000000' ,'480000000', '543000000' , '600000000']    
    global_id_entry=Label(text=str(global_id))
    global_id_entry.place(x=50,y=50+60*(global_id+1))                          
   
    a_dict['global_id'][global_id]=global_id
    
    unique_dag_id_entry=Label(text=str(global_id))
    unique_dag_id_entry.place(x=330,y=50+60*(global_id+1)) 
    a_dict['unique_dag_id'][global_id]=unique_dag_id_entry
    
    wcet_cpu_entry=Entry(app)
    wcet_cpu_entry.place(x=450,y=50+60*(global_id+1)) 
    a_dict['wcet_cpu'][global_id]=wcet_cpu_entry
    
    wcet_gpu_entry=Entry(app)
    wcet_gpu_entry.place(x=600,y=50+60*(global_id+1))
    a_dict['wcet_gpu'][global_id]=wcet_gpu_entry

    deadline_entry=Entry(app)
    deadline_entry.place(x=750,y=50+60*(global_id+1))   
    a_dict['deadline'][global_id]=(deadline_entry)

    input_arrival_time_entry=Entry(app)
    input_arrival_time_entry.place(x=900,y=50+60*(global_id+1))  
    a_dict['input_arrival_time'][global_id]=(input_arrival_time_entry)

    hyper_period_entry_entry=Entry(app)
    hyper_period_entry_entry.place(x=1050,y=50+60*(global_id+1))  
    a_dict['hyper_period_entry'][global_id]=(hyper_period_entry_entry)

    input_task_period_entry=Entry(app)
    input_task_period_entry.place(x=1200,y=50+60*(global_id+1)) 
    a_dict['input_task_period'][global_id]=( input_task_period_entry)
    
    platform_id_drop=ttk.Combobox(app,values=platform_id_options)
    platform_id_drop.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",selo)
    platform_id_drop.place(x=150,y=50+60*(global_id+1))
    a_dict['platform_id'][global_id]=platform_id_drop

    
    combobox_b = ttk.Combobox(app,values=v)
    combobox_b.place(x=1350,y=50+60*(global_id+1))
    a_dict['frequency'][global_id]=( combobox_b )
    
    v.clear()
    global_id=global_id+1
    z=z-1
    

button=Button(app,text="save_info",command=save_trace1)
button.place(x=0,y=0)

app.mainloop()
'''
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Tkinter Comboboxes where the displayed values depend on the user-choice in the other boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67110893/multiple-tkinter-comboboxes-where-the-displayed-values-depend-on-the-user-choice)

Comment: Does this has solved you query or may I write the code? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67110893/multiple-tkinter-comboboxes-where-the-displayed-values-depend-on-the-user-choice